# Why can't we directly change a group from global scope to domain local or vice versa?

Tags: active-directory

If we need to change the scope of a group from global to domain local or vice versa we first need to change it to Universal. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you cannot do it, because some checks should be done. For example if group's scope is Domain Local and it contains foreign principals (i.e. accounts from external AD Forest), the conversion is not possible:

[image]

Other reason may be that the UI and APIs are rather old and Microsoft have had decided not to add new functionalities - who knows (:

**UPDATE:**
I've tested changing group's scope with PowerShell:

```
Get-ADGroup testgroup | Set-ADGroup -GroupScope Global
```

The result is similar:

```
Set-ADGroup : The request is not supported
```

So actually the check is performed by the domain controller, which returns error 50 (0x32) - ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.

That means to me - there is no such built in functionality, because in most cases conversion expects manual work i.e. removing foreign principals etc.

Comment: I suppose I'll take that as the answer. Still it keeps bugging me. Not able to accept that they would keep such a flow without any reason(or just because they have decided not to add new functionalities).

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it, given that the group doesn't yet have any conflicting membership. You can convert it to universal, then back to domain local.

Comment: so a workaround is, if you already used the group for a lot of permissioning, remove conflicting members, convert the type, add members back.

Answer (score 0):

This had me stuck for a minute as well.
The following solution worked for me:

```
Set-ADGroup -Identity (FolderName) -GroupScope Domainlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$results = get-adgroup -filter {name -like "rename_me*"} -server | sort name  
$results | Set-ADGroup -GroupScope Universal  
$results | Set-ADGroup -GroupScope Global  
$results += get-adgroup -filter {name -like "rename_me*"} -server | sort name  
$results | export-csv C:\Scripts\results.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Even now it seems that you can't change group DomainLocal scope to Global scope directly. You still need to switch it over to Universal scope first.

If you have a bunch of groups with DomainLocal scope that you need to change to Global scope try the following Powershell to make the task easier:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=somelocation,DC=domain,DC=local" | ForEach-Object { Set-ADGroup -identity $_.Name -groupscope Universal }
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=somelocation,DC=domain,DC=local" | ForEach-Object { Set-ADGroup -identity $_.Name -groupscope Global }
```